# Missing icons at the bottom of the home screen with TouchWiz

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-ace

My son has recently got a Samsung Galaxy Ace android phone. Somehow he has managed to remove three of the four icons that are normally at the bottom of the screen ( typically the green icon for making a call, the contacts icons etc ).

The bottom screen has now only one button a blue box with four small white squares in it.

How do I get the missing buttons back?

To be specific the buttons that have gone are "Phone", "Contacts" and "Messaging". Instead of being on the bar at the bottom of the screen they are now on the wallpaper with all the other icons.

Answer (score 5):

That's a little bit tricky with Touchwiz.

In order to move app links in and out of the icon bar at the bottom on phones with Touchwiz, you have to *enter the app list (App Drawer)* via the blue menu icon. This is the only icon that can't be removed. Then press the left hardware key and *choose edit*, but make sure that you are in the "Customizable Grid" view type. You should now be able to reorganize all icons in the app menu and on the space where the lower 4 buttons are, by using **drag and drop**. Simply long press an icon and move it where you want.